# How to translate message.text in magento 2

Tags: magento2, messages, js-translation

i want translate " The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart ". I think it's in the template but when I find it, it's here

app\design\frontend\Mgs\dukaken\Magento_Theme\templates\messages.phtml

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
    <div data-bind="attr: {
        class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
        'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
    }">
        <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        <div class="cl-mes"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
    <div data-bind="attr: {
        class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
        'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
    }">
        <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        <div class="cl-mes"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to translate it and other things in it, please help me. Thanks all

[image: 2]

**UPDATE**

I want translate " Box not available. "

[image]

I added to csv like this, it not translate

```
"Box not available.","Box nicht verfügbar.",module,Magento_Checkout
"not available.","nicht verfügbar.",module,Magento_Checkout
"Box not available.","Box nicht verfügbar.",module,Magento_GiftRegistry
"not available.","nicht verfügbar.",module,Magento_GiftRegistry
"Box not available.","Box nicht verfügbar.",module,Magento_Bundle
"not available.","nicht verfügbar.",module,Magento_Bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
<div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
```

Use

```
<div data-bind="i18n: message.text"></div>
```

Be sure you have added the text translation in your respective csv file.

```
 "%1 not available.","%1 nicht verfügbar."
```

Where %1 is your product name referred in your file.

Comment: Hi aravind, can you help me custom error message " [ name product ]  not available " in magento 2, i can't translate it, i added it to csv but not work.

Comment: How did you translate in csv ..Place that text too and update the question.

Comment: Please check update question

Comment: what is the name of CSV file name? and also the folder path you have placed that csv in your theme..

Comment: de_DE.csv, file csv working but only " Box not available. " not translate, i used csv to translate "The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart"

Comment: where does this message showing checkout page?

Comment: no, after click button add to cart, it show this message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95271/discussion-between-aravind-and-tn98).